# I'm getting java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind when i try to listen and bind a client to same port

Tags: java, server, io, netty, serversocket

I'm getting the above exception while trying to establish a `server` and create a `client` to another server using the netty framework.

I have 2 java files:

1. One is `Server Acceptor` meant to listen at a `port` say `9999`
2. and another class file `Client Connector` to connect to another
   server but bound with the `port` `9999`.

Once both these files are executed I should be able to listen as a server in `port 9999` and also send a message to remote server bound to same `port 9999`.
Since the remote server guy accepts and sends message to same port of my server.(`9999` in this case)

My `ServerAcceptor.class` runs successfully and listens in `port 9999`. But my `ClientConnector.class` complains that the port is already bound.

Now how can i send and receive in the same port?

My Client code is as below.

```
ClientTest clientTest =new ClientTest();
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
     Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
     bootstrap.group(group);
     bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new MyClientHandler(clientTest));
     bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY,true).option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR,true).option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    System.out.println("Connecting to Server");         

    ChannelFuture channelFuture;
    try {
        channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8888),new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9999)).sync();
        channelFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture)
            throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Client");
            if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("Client has connected successfully");
            } else {
            System.err.println("Client could not connect to the sever");
            channelFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            } );
```

Comment: I have added the client part code here..I'm getting this exception when connect method is getting executed.bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8888),new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9999)).sync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once both these files are executed I should be able to listen as a server in port 9999 and also send a message to remote server bound to same port 9999.

No you shouldn't. The system will not permit it. It will only permit *inbound* connections to share the listening port. Your requirement, assuming you have interpreted it correctly, is infeasible.

> Since the remote server guy accepts and sends message to same port of my server.(9999 in this case)

This doesn't begin to make sense. If the remote server accepts connections, he will communicate over those connections, whatever their source port may have been. He doesn't care. Possibly what is really happening I s that he also listens on port 9999. In any case none of this imposes a requirement for you to specify a local outbound port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there some other means through which this can be implemented..

Comment: What part of 'infeasible' didn't you understand? What is the actual point of your requirement (assuming, again, that you have interpreted it correctly)? What is your reason for specifying a local outbound port at all?

Comment: My requirement is that I should keep listening to a port for inbound messages from a Third party Server(TPS). At specific time interval, I should send echo messages to the TPS. TPS demands that this echo message should have originated from the same port in which I'm listening as a server.

Comment: I can only repeat. This is infeasible. You have misunderstood. Possibly, for example, you are required to send these messages over an existing accepted connection, not a new outbound connection.